# How do I perform a string function whilst using OPENJSON WITH?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In this example, `DT_RowId` is a concatenated string.  I need to extract out its values, and make them available in a `WHERE` clause (not shown).

Is there a way to perform string functions on a value as part of a `FROM OPENJSON WITH`?

Is there a proper way to extract concatenated strings from a value without using a clunky `SELECT` statement?

Side note:  This example is REALLY part of an `UPDATE` statement, so I'd be using the extracted values in the `WHERE` clause (not shown here).  Also, also:  Split is a custom string function we have.

BTW:  I have full control of that `DT_RowId`, and i could make it an array, for example, `[42, 1, 1]`

```
declare @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) = '{"DT_RowId":"42_1_14","Action":"edit","Schedule":"1","Slot":"1","Period":"9:00 to 9:30 UPDATED","AMOnly":"0","PMOnly":"0","AllDay":"1"}'




        select
            (select Item from master.dbo.Split(source.DT_RowId, '_', 0) where ItemIndex = 0) as ID
           ,source.Schedule
           ,source.Slot
           ,source.[Period]
           ,source.AllDay
           ,source.PMOnly
           ,source.AMOnly
        from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
        with
        (
                DT_RowId varchar(255) '$.DT_RowId' /*concatenated string of row being edited */
                ,Schedule tinyint '$.Schedule'
                ,Slot tinyint '$.Slot'
                ,[Period] varchar(20) '$.Period'
                ,AllDay bit '$.AllDay'
                ,PMOnly bit '$.PMOnly'
                ,AMOnly bit '$.AMOnly'
        ) as source
```

Comment: *"Is there a proper way to extract concatenated strings from a value without using a clunky SELECT statement?"* No, normally you would use an **inline** table-value function in the `FROM`. (*Or, even better, not store delimited data at all.*) Specifically here you probably `STRING_SPLIT`. i'm not sure why you're using a custom function in when you're clearly using SQL Server 2017. I'm really not sure why that function is in `master` as well.

Comment: @Larnu It's a custom function our department has had for eons.  as far as I know, the new built-in function `string_split` doesn't have any way to reference the index of the extracted items --- and even if it did, I don't know how to get those values into this query.

Comment: No, after many complaints, `STRING_SPLIT`, still does not provide the ordinal position. It is why many people use `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`.

Comment: @Larnu OPENJSON is available in 2016 version as well. What makes you think the OP is clearly using 2017 version?

Comment: "BTW: I have full control of that DT_RowId" Well, what's the problem of separating the content of the `DT_ROWId` into multiple properties in the json, then? Seems like the obvious choice to me...

Comment: Could well have been a "fat finger" @ZoharPeled, as yes `OPENJSON` was added in 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL-Server 2016+ offers a nice trick to split a string fast and position-aware:

```
    select
        DTRow.AsJson as DTRow_All_Content
       ,JSON_VALUE(DTRow.AsJson,'$[0]') AS DTRow_FirstValue
       ,source.Schedule
       ,source.Slot
       ,source.[Period]
       ,source.AllDay
       ,source.PMOnly
       ,source.AMOnly
    from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
    with
    (
            DT_RowId varchar(255) '$.DT_RowId' /*concatenated string of row being edited */
            ,Schedule tinyint '$.Schedule'
            ,Slot tinyint '$.Slot'
            ,[Period] varchar(20) '$.Period'
            ,AllDay bit '$.AllDay'
            ,PMOnly bit '$.PMOnly'
            ,AMOnly bit '$.AMOnly'
    ) as source
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT CONCAT('["',REPLACE([source].DT_RowId,'_','","'),'"]')) DTRow(AsJson);
```

The magic is the transformation of `42_1_14` to `["42","1","14"]` with some simple string methods. With this you can use `JSON_VALUE()` to fetch an item by its position.

General hint: If you have *full control of DT_RowId* you should rather create this JSON array right from the start and avoid hacks while reading this...

## update

Just to demonstrate how this would run, if the value was a JSON-array, check this out:

```
declare @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) = '{"DT_RowId":["42","1","14"]}'

select
    source.DT_RowId as DTRow_All_Content
   ,JSON_VALUE(source.DT_RowId,'$[0]') AS DTRow_FirstValue
from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
with
(
        DT_RowId NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON 
) as source;
```

## update 2

Just to add a little to your self-answer:

We must think of JSON as a *special string*. As there is no native JSON data type, the engine does not know, when the string is a string, and when it is JSON.

Using `NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON` in the `WITH`-clause allows to deal with the return value again with JSON methods. For example, we could use `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(UseTheValueHere)` to dive into nested lists and objects.

Actually there's no need to use this at all. If there are no repeating elements, one could just parse all the values directly:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonRequest,'$.DT_RowId[0]') AS DTRowId_1
      ,JSON_VALUE(@jsonRequest,'$.Action') AS [Action]
      --and so on...
```

But this would mean to parse the JSON over and over, which is very expensive.

Using `OPENJSON` means to read the whole JSON in one single pass (on the current level) and return the elements found (with or without a JSON path) in a derived set (one row for each element).

The `WITH`-clause is meant to perform kind of `PIVOT`-action and returns the elements as a multi-column-set. The additional advantage is, that you can specify the data type and - if necessary - a differing JSON path and the column's alias.

You can use any valid JSON path (as well in the `WITH`-clause as in `JSON_VALUE()` or in many other places). That means that there are several ways to get the same result. Understanding how the engine works, will enable you to find the most performant approach.

Comment: Awesome!!!  So...  I'll change my DT_RowId to an `[array]`, then, declare it as JSON in the `WITH` section, and then I can use `JSON_VALUE` to extract specific values from the array where necessary!?!?!  :)

Comment: @raydlevel5 yes, exactly 

Answer (score 1):

OP here.  Just expanding on the answer I accepted by Shnugo, with some details and notes...  Hopefully all this might help somebody out there.

- I am going to make DT_RowId an array
- I will use `AS JSON` for DT_RowId in the `OPENJSON WITH` statement
- I can then treat it as a json structure, and use `JSON_VALUE` to extract a value at a specific index

  ```
  declare @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) = '{"DT_RowId":["42", "1", "14"],"Action":"edit","Schedule":"1","Slot":"1","Period":"9:00 to 9:30 UPDATED","AMOnly":"0","PMOnly":"0","AllDay":"1"}'




  select
      source.DT_RowId as DTRowId_FULL_JSON_Struct /*the full array*/
      ,JSON_VALUE(source.DT_RowId,'$[0]') AS JSON_VAL_0 /*extract value at index 0 from json structure*/
      ,JSON_VALUE(source.DT_RowId,'$[1]') AS JSON_VAL_1 /*extract value at index 1 from json structure*/
      ,JSON_VALUE(source.DT_RowId,'$[2]') AS JSON_VAL_2 /*extract value at index 2 from json structure*/
     ,source.DT_RowId_Index0 /*already extracted*/
     ,source.DT_RowId_Index1 /*already extracted*/
     ,source.DT_RowId_Index2 /*already extracted*/
     ,source.Schedule
     ,source.Slot
     ,source.Period
     ,source.AllDay
     ,source.PMOnly
     ,source.AMOnly
  from openjson(@jsonRequest, '$')
  with
  (

          DT_RowId nvarchar(max) as json  /*format as json; do the rest in the SELECT statement*/
          ,DT_RowId_Index0 varchar(2) '$.DT_RowId[0]' /*When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys.*/
          ,DT_RowId_Index1 varchar(2) '$.DT_RowId[1]' /*When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys.*/
          ,DT_RowId_Index2 varchar(2) '$.DT_RowId[2]' /*When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys.*/
          ,Schedule tinyint '$.Schedule'
          ,Slot tinyint '$.Slot'
          ,[Period] varchar(20) '$.Period'
          ,AllDay bit '$.AllDay'
          ,PMOnly bit '$.PMOnly'
          ,AMOnly bit '$.AMOnly'
  ) as source
  ```

Comment: Great, that you are helping the community with your findings. I added some additions to my answer. You might want to read *update 2*